# auto restart delayed job worker in nginx

Tags: nginx, delayed-job

I found that on my rails vps production server with nginx passenger will failed when going through heavy process. Is there any way that I can restart my delayed job worker when it get failed?

Answer (score 1):

You could just go with upstart or systemd; there's [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722675/is-there-benefit-to-using-monit-instead-of-a-basic-upstart-setup) that could get you started with whether going that basic is sufficient or not.

A good overview of the problem and solution space would be [here](http://centos-vn.blogspot.com/2014/06/daemon-showdown-upstart-vs-runit-vs.html). It's a bit outdated (2 years old), but to give you a basic handle on the problem and solution space you're looking at would be a good jumping off point.